# objc_msgSend crash : how can I find where?

Tags: iphone, crash, mkmapview

enabled nszombies
Is there any additional information anyone can see in this debug log that I could use to find the problem?

```
(gdb) bt  
0  0x30b7eca4 in objc_msgSend ()  
1  0x36179302 in -[MKMapView annotationContainer:viewForAnnotation:] ()  
2  0x36178f94 in -[MKAnnotationContainerView _addViewForAnnotation:] ()  
3  0x361a2faa in -[MKAnnotationContainerView userLocationAnnotationWillShow] ()  
4  0x3619fcbe in -[MKMapView(UserPositioningInternal) _runPositioningChange] ()  
5  0x3619da8c in -[MKMapView(UserPositioningInternal) _startPositioningChange:] ()  
6  0x361a1050 in -[MKMapView(UserPositioningInternal) locationManagerUpdatedLocation:] ()  
7  0x365cff02 in -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:] ()  
8  0x3660d2f8 in -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:] ()  
9  0x36190808 in -[MKLocationManager _reportLocationStatus:] ()  
10 0x36191d72 in -[MKLocationManager _reportLocationSuccess] ()
11 0x361919cc in -[MKLocationManager locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:] ()  
12 0x33bfbc2c in -[CLLocationManager onClientEventLocation:] ()  
13 0x33bfbf48 in -[CLLocationManager onClientEvent:supportInfo:] ()  
14 0x33bfdd04 in OnClientEventInternal ()  
15 0x33bf57a2 in CLClientInvokeCallback ()  
16 0x33bf7c46 in CLClientHandleDaemonDataLocation ()  
17 0x33bf7d9c in CLClientHandleDaemonData ()  
18 0x3663070c in __CFMessagePortPerform ()    
19 0x36639a96 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()  
20 0x3663b83e in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()  
21 0x3663c60c in __CFRunLoopRun ()  
22 0x365ccec2 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()  
23 0x365ccdca in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()  
24 0x313c141e in GSEventRunModal ()  
25 0x313c14ca in GSEventRun ()  
26 0x33390d68 in -[UIApplication _run] ()  
27 0x3338e806 in UIApplicationMain ()  
28 0x000039ca in main (argc=1, argv=0x2fdff55c) at main.m:14    
(gdb)
```

UPDATE:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{


 MKAnnotationView* annView = nil;

    if ( [annotation isKindOfClass: [AnnotationItem class]] )
    {
        MKPinAnnotationView* pin = (MKPinAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier: kListingAnnotationIdentifier];

        if ( nil == pin )
        {
            pin = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation: annotation reuseIdentifier: kListingAnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];
        }
        else
        {
            [pin setAnnotation: annotation];
        }

        pin.canShowCallout = YES;

        pin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;


        UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed: @"logap.png"] ;
        pin.leftCalloutAccessoryView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: img] autorelease];


        pin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

        annView = pin;

    }
    return annView;



}
```

Comment: Can you post code for viewForAnnotation method?

Comment: Hardly he can, MKMapView is in Apple's MapKit framework.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it! I updated my question with the code. It happens infrequently, I can hardly reproduce it.

Comment: Any update on this?  I'm getting a crash at the same place, often when our app resumes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your debug log shows a crash when the mapView is trying to display (a change in) the user's location. User location is an annotation of class `MKUserLocation`, and if that annotation gets passed to your implementation of `mapView:viewForAnnotation`, your code returns a pointer to `nil` (that is, it returns an `MKAnnotationView` object named `annView`, whose value is set to `nil`).

So I suspect you're crashing when the user's location appears or moves on screen, or that the difference between `nil` and "an `MKAnnotationView` object whose value is set to `nil`" may suddenly matter to Cocoa at hard-to-reproduce times. Try testing for whether the annotation is of class `MKUserLocation`, and explicitly returning `nil` in this case.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I think you are on the right track since it crashes less on wifi and more on an actual iPhone. Here is what I put in.          if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) 
    {
        return nil;
    }                // I am not really sure though what is the difference, since the original implementation would also return nil.

Comment: Actually I see what you meant now. returning  MKAnnotationView* annView = nil; vs returning nil. Well I put it in. Let's see if it makes a difference. Will keep you updated, and thanks again.